# How do I interpret JSON if jQuery thinks it is receiving a JSONP request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to grab some API data from a website (in particular Yummly) and it looks like when I try to do a JSONP request I receive JSON data. This results in an "Uncaught SyntaxError: UnexpectedToken:".

The code which tries to do this is:

```
var keywords = $('#input-text').val();
var url = "http://www.yummly.com/api/recipesq="+keywords+"&_app_id=<snipped-app-id>&_app_key=<snipped-api-key>&";
 $.ajax({                                                                            
      type: 'GET',
       url: url,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       //dataType: 'jsonp json'
       success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },
       error: function(data, data2) { console.log(data); },
       //jsonp: false,
       //jsonpCallback: 'recipeGet'                                          
  });
});
```

I have tried to convert to JSON from the JSONP by overloading dataType, however this did not result in any different result than the above. I have also tried changing the callback function, but when I receive the syntax error it does not go to the function. When I do not use JSONP and just use JSON I receive a, "XMLHttpRequest cannot load  Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.".

Any help would be appreciated, i've been struggling with this for quite a bit.

Comment: Does the service your are gettng data from explicitly support `JSONP`? If they don't, then you can't use `JSONP`. if they also do not support `CORS` headers, then you simply cannot use this data source via AJAX on other domains. What exactly does the response look like?

Comment: @RPM that won't help because the raw response text isn't available in a JSONP request.

Comment: Further to what Alex Wayne said, if the site only supplies JSON you could do a normal Ajax request to your own webserver, and then have your server-side code make a request to the other site and return its response back to the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am one of the developers responsible for the Yummly API.

The Yummly API supports JSONP (the [documentation](https://developer.yummly.com/intro) explains how) but there are several problems with your request.

1. The API url should be

   http ://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes (remove the space after http)
2. There should be a '?' between /recipes and q (q is a parameter, /v1/api/recipes is the path)
3. You can then pass a callback parameter as usual with a JSONP call ($.ajax with dataType: 'JSONP' like you are using above should work)

Finally, your app_key is secret. Please don't publish it on public sites like Stack Overflow. I've revoked it, please go to https://developer.yummly.com to generate a new one.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! Sorry about the API key, in my rush to try and get this problem fixed I didn't think I should have taken it out. It seems my problem was with appending the 'api.' suffix to the url. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Registers to answer question about the API he's working on. Top Bloke!